# What is the Pythonic way to make an immutable class?

Tags: python, object, immutability

I'm currently working with some data structures in Python, and I would like them to be hashable (so they can be stored in dictionaries and sets). So far I've seen three main ways to do this:

① Make a normal class and give it a `__hash__` method.

```
class DataStructure:
    def __init__(self, member):
        self.member = member
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.member)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, DataStructure) and self.member == other.member
```

But this is just "trusting" the end user to never mutate `member`. If they do mutate it while it's stored in a set or dictionary, Bad Things result.

② Use `collections.namedtuple`.

```
DataStructure = collections.namedtuple('DataStructure', ('member',))
```

But a `namedtuple` can't have member functions, and it would be really nice to have member functions.

③ Use `__slots__` and override `__setattr__`, as shown [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/01/17/how-to-create-immutable-classes-in-python/).

```
class DataStructure:
    __slots__ = ['member']
    def __init__(self, member):
        super(DataStructure, self).__setattr__('member', member)
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        raise ValueError('Mutating this object is Not Allowed')
    # also define __hash__ and __eq__ here
```

But this [doesn't seem to be intended usage](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/531365/), and also makes inheritance more complicated. Above all it doesn't feel "Pythonic".

So: **what is the preferred way of making an immutable class in Python?** Wanting a custom data structure to be hashable doesn't seem like such a strange desire—that's why `__hash__` exists, after all. And I'd prefer to actually make the class immutable rather than telling users "you're free to assign to these members, but if you do, your sets and dictionaries could crash and burn"—Python generally tries not to let people make those mistakes in the first place (which is why `set` and `frozenset` are distinct).

Comment: How would you compare equality of each instance? If that’s an easy answer then you should be able devise a hash off that.. it leans toward that in the docs. Besides should override eq and hash methods anyway if doing one.

Comment: @Jab Oh, writing the hash and eq methods is easy. The problem is that they depend on member variables of the class, and those can be mutated by the user. Which would change the hash after instantiation, which is bad.

Comment: Subclass an immutable type, like a string, frozenset, or tuple, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute immutablility is probably impossible to achieve, but you can use [properties](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) to make your intent clear:

```
class DataStructure:
    def __init__(self, member):
        self._member = member
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.member)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, DataStructure) and self.member == other.member
    @property
    def member(self):
        return self._member
```

This way `member` is exposed as a "public" attribute, but is not writeable:

```
>>> ds = DataStructure(42)
>>> ds.member
42
>>> ds.member = 56
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

A determined end user could still mutate `self._member`, but at this point you would expect that they *know* they are doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

Prepend a '_' in front of a variable that you want to be "read-only". It can still be changed from inside the class, but IDE's won't predict it and will throw warnings if you try and change them from outside the class.

```py
__slots__ = ('_member',)
```

Comment: To clarify, will the IDE throw a warning, or will Python itself?

Comment: The IDE will throw a warning